# How do I use setRetainInstance (a Fragment method) when I'm using a FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I want to use `setRetainInstance(true)` on my `FragmentActivity` so that `onCreate()` will not be called every time the screen rotates. I just want to adjust the layout to the screen adjusting without reestablishing my location services connection and notifying the user. How should this be done?

Comment: How should this be done? Well what? Retain a fragment? or "preserve your location services connection" (whatever that is) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by reading the Fragment [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) about what setRetainInstance does (And does not).

In summary:

> public void setRetainInstance (boolean retain)
>
> Added in API level 11 Control whether a fragment instance is retained
>   across Activity re-creation (such as from a configuration change).
>   This can only be used with fragments not in the back stack. If set,
>   the fragment lifecycle will be slightly different when an activity is
>   recreated:
>
> onDestroy() will not be called (but onDetach() still will be, because
>   the fragment is being detached from its current activity).
>   onCreate(Bundle) will not be called since the fragment is not being
>   re-created. onAttach(Activity) and onActivityCreated(Bundle) will
>   still be called.

With that in mind, make sure your "location services connection" and such are located in a place where they will not die (they probably shouldn't be in either Activity or Fragment anyway).

Answer (score 1):

This paragraph is taken from a book I'm currently reading "Professional Android 4 Application Development"

> If an Activity is destroyed and restarted to handle a hardware
>   configuration change, such as the screen orientation changing, you can
>   request that your Fragment instance be retained. By calling
>   setRetainInstance within a Fragment’s onCreate handler, you specify
>   that Fragment’s instance should not be killed and restarted when its
>   associated Activity is re-created.

I think that's clear enough.

Regards!